# Is it possible to get multiple bounds from the Ramsey-like recursion $f(t) \leq f(t-1)^2$?

Tags: recursion, ramsey-theory

The motivation for this question comes from recursions found in Ramsey theory. The Ramsey number $R(s,t)$ is equal to the minimum $n$ such that for any red-blue coloring of the edges of some $K_n$, one is guaranteed to be able to find some red $K_s$-subgraph of $K_n$ or some blue $K_t$-subgraph of $K_n$. To show that $R(s,t)$ is finite, it is common to prove the recursion $R(s,t) \leq R(s-1,t) + R(s,t-1)$ (see for example the proof in the [Wikipedia for Ramsey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Proof)).

By induction, one can prove multiple bounds using this recursion. Two examples of such bounds are
$$R(s,t) \leq 2^{s+t} \quad \text{and} \quad  R(s,t) \leq \binom{s+t-2}{s-1}.$$

While thinking about a finite version of the canonical Ramsey theorem, I have come across another recursion. Namely for some function $f(t)$, we have the recursion $f(t)\leq f(t-1)^2$. It is not difficult to show (again by induction) that
$$f(t) \leq 2^{2^t}.$$
**My main curiosity:** Given that there are multiple bounds for $R(s,t)$ by a single recursion, are there are there other/better upper bounds we can prove for $f(t)$ using this recursion? More generally, given some recursion such as this, is there a way to prove that some upper bound is "as good as possible"? If not, I'd be quite curious as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot, in fact, prove *any* bounds using the recursion alone. Bounds like $R(s,t) \le 2^{s+t}$ and $R(s,t) \le \binom{s+t-2}{s-1}$ are shown by a combination of the inequality $R(s,t) \le R(s,t-1) + R(s-1,t)$ and some base cases. What we can prove depends on the base cases we assume.

In the case of Ramsey numbers, the most we can say without *any* hard work is that $R(s,2) = s$ and $R(2,t) = t$. If you color the edges of $K_s$ red and blue, either you get a blue $K_2$ (a blue edge) or the entire $K_s$ is red.

We can figure out the best thing we can prove using only the information above. To do so, define an upper bound $U(s,t)$ by the initial conditions $U(s,2)=s$ and $U(2,t)=t$. Then, for $s>2$ and $t>2$, define $U(s,t)$ to be *equal* to $U(s,t-1)+U(s-1,t)$. We can conclude that $R(s,t) \le U(s,t)$ for all $t$. But we are now in a position to determine what $U(s,t)$ is equal to, and we can derive the closed form $U(s,t) = \binom{s+t-2}{s-1}$. Therefore $R(s,t) \le \binom{s+t-2}{s-1}$ (for all $s,t \ge 2$) is the best thing we can prove without bringing in any additional facts about Ramsey numbers.

But, for example, suppose that we somehow proved that for all $t \ge 3$, $R(3,t) \le \frac{14}{15} \binom{t+2}{2}$. (I'm not sure if this is something we know.) Then we would be able to use the same method to prove that $R(s,t) \le \frac{14}{15}\binom{s+t-2}{s-1}$ for all $s,t \ge 3$.

---

Similarly, if we have $f(t) \le f(t-1)^2$, then we can prove that $f(t) \le f(0)^{2^t}$, and if $f(0) = 2$, then the best thing we can prove from that information is that $f(t) \le 2^{2^t}$. If it happens to be true that $f(2)=11$, then the best thing we can prove from *there* is $f(3) \le 11^2$, $f(4) \le 11^4$, $f(5) \le 11^8$, and in general $f(t) \le 11^{2^{t-2}}$. All these bounds are of the form $a \cdot b^{2^t}$, but the exact values of $a$ and $b$ depend on what initial conditions you can prove.

Comment: Aha! So recursions like this allow us to build up to an upper bound BUT that bound is dependent on where we began (the basecase). Much thanks!